# CAS policy Error

Tags: asp.net, activereports

please, someone can help me to fix this error, "This method implicitly uses CAS policy, which has been obsoleted by the .NET Framework. In order to enable CAS policy for compatibility, please use the NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy configuration switch." I can not generate my pdf files. it's an Asp.Net application to host on a Win 2008 R2 server. IIS 6.5. I already added

```
<runtime>
      <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true" />
</runtime>
```

in my web.config but it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because CAS policy is obsolete in .net Framework 4.0. The Xml node you've added is for Windows Forms applications. For Web applications, please add the following in web.config:

```
<system.web>
   <trust legacyCasModel="true"/>
</system.web>
```